# Creating a clear ggplot graph against two categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to begin by apologizing for not putting enough effort in asking my questions. I noticed they are not clear and abide by the rules that the community asks to help better assist you as well as myself.

I have been having trouble with my code, and I am not sure how to make a clear cut graph as I wish to make it.

The question goes as follows: Make a bar plot displaying the count of each teams league wins. The graph must be as clear and readable as possible.

This is my code:

```
   library(Lahman)
   library(ggplot2)
   library(dplyr)
   library(reshape2)
   Teams %>% group_by(teamID) %>% 
     filter(!is.na(LgWin == "Y")) %>% 
     ggplot(Teams, mapping = aes(teamID, ..count..)) + 
     geom_bar(mapping = aes(fill = LgWin))
```

The picture does not make any sense. Please help.

[image: The picture does not make any sense. Please help.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the end you want to plot the number of rows each teamId has LgWin == "Y" right? if so you can do this:

```
Teams %>% 
  filter(LgWin == "Y") %>% 
  group_by(teamID) %>% 
  summarise(number_of_wins = n()) %>% 
  transform(., teamID = reorder(teamID, number_of_wins)) %>% 
  ggplot(., mapping = aes(x = teamID, number_of_wins)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", mapping = aes(fill = number_of_wins)) +
  coord_flip()
```

with this result:

[image]

hope this helps...

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.